# Apple Music Next Slide Animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation, transition

I would like to recreate the animation when you click the section "next, connect" at the bottom of this page

http://www.apple.com/music/radio/

does anyone know how to recreate this in JS or CSS3 for perfect page transitions?

Comment: Click on 'next, connect' leads to another page, not sure what you refer to?

Comment: @nevermind when you click "connect" a animation happens where the image goes to full screen, than loads the content. That's what Im looking for

Comment: Ah, so... works in Chrome, doesn't work in Firefox...

Comment: @nevermind any idea how they achieved this?

Comment: No, to be honest. :)

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for information about what is on-topic on SO. Currently, this question is far too broad; you're asking us to write a lot of code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use simple padding for the effect

```
padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
```

and transition for the animation!

```
transition: all 0.3s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s64bamwL/)

Comment: Thanks! maybe to make it full screen instead of padding being added I will add the calc(100vh) so it stretches to 100% viewport height!

Comment: This is a very nice idea!